# Linux Images wont show up on main root folder but will on a subfolder

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, containers, lamp

I have playing with some docker containers with LAMP.

The issue I am facing is that if I put my webpage to the www folder the page is showing up but the images from the folder www/icons/test.png wont show up. (http://192.168.123.123:8082/icons/test.png)
I get

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at 192.168.123.123 Port 8082
```

I made a copy of the icons folder to a subfolder www/test/icons/test.png and its working fine!
If I change path on the webpage all good.(http://192.168.123.123:8082/test/icons/test.png)

I checked the permissions for both folders and subfiles and they are the same!

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 userwh2 userwh2 4096 Aug  2 08:53 www

drwxr-xr-x 2 userwh2 userwh2   4096 Aug  1 10:19 www/icons
-rw-r--r-x 1 userwh2 userwh2  12145 Jul 24  2020 www/icons/test.png

drwxr-xr-x 3 userwh2 userwh2   4096 Aug  2 08:52 www/test
drwxr-xr-x 2 userwh2 userwh2 4096 Aug  1 10:19 www/test/icons
-rw-r--r-x 1 userwh2 userwh2  12145 Jul 24  2020 www/test/icons/test.png
```

I cant figure it out....
Any ideas anyone?

Edit:
Found this in the log:
Cannot serve directory /usr/share/apache2/icons/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was able to find an answer
https://forum.getkirby.com/t/subpage-not-working-after-digital-ocean-deployment/16083/41

Seems like the /icons folder name its used by apache2 when doing a lookup and that is why its getting confused. Its like a common name probably in apache (ex, root, etc)